# How to prepend array to each element of another array with my choice of key and value (in php)?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

This code :

```
for ($p=0;$p<count($results);$p++){
    foreach ($results[$p] as $k => $v){
        $typeee = ['type' => strtolower(str_replace('_','',$results[$p][$k]['metric']))."container"];
        array_insert2($results[$p],0,$typeee);
    }
}
print_r($results);
```

gives me this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => pagestoriescontainer
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => pagestories
                    [object_id] => 123456778
                    [metric] => page_stories
                    [end_time] => 1386057600
                    [period] => 86400
                    [value] => 2090
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => pagestorytellers
                    [object_id] => 123456778
                    [metric] => page_storytellers
                    [end_time] => 1386057600
                    [period] => 86400
                    [value] => 2041
                )


 [...]

[1] => Array
        (

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => pagestories
                    [object_id] => 199193463123456778
                    [metric] => page_stories
                    [end_time] => 1386057600
                    [period] => 86400
                    [value] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => pagestorytellers
                    [object_id] => 199193463123456778
                    [metric] => page_storytellers
                    [end_time] => 1386057600
                    [period] => 86400
                    [value] => 0
                )

   [...]
```

But this code:

```
for ($p=0;$p<count($results);$p++){
    foreach ($results[$p] as $k => $v){ 
        $typeee = ['type' => strtolower(str_replace('_','',$results[$p][$k]['metric']))."container"];
        array_insert2($results[$p],$k,$typeee);
    }
}
```

DOES NOT give me this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => pagestoriescontainer
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => pagestories
                    [object_id] => 123456778
                    [metric] => page_stories
                    [end_time] => 1386057600
                    [period] => 86400
                    [value] => 2090
                )
            [type] => pagestorytellerscontainer
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => pagestorytellers
                    [object_id] => 123456778
                    [metric] => page_storytellers
                    [end_time] => 1386057600
                    [period] => 86400
                    [value] => 2041
                )


 [...]

[1] => Array
        (
            [type] => pagestoriescontainer
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => pagestories
                    [object_id] => 199193463123456778
                    [metric] => page_stories
                    [end_time] => 1386057600
                    [period] => 86400
                    [value] => 0
                )
            [type] => pagestorytellerscontainer
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => pagestorytellers
                    [object_id] => 199193463123456778
                    [metric] => page_storytellers
                    [end_time] => 1386057600
                    [period] => 86400
                    [value] => 0
                )

   [...]
```

Why? How can I get what I want? :)

Also,

```
function array_insert2 (&$array, $position, $insert_array) {  
    $first_array = array_splice ($array, 0, $position);
    $array = array_merge ($first_array, $insert_array, $array);
}
```

Comment: PROTIP: When formatting code, use the `{}` button, not the `"` button on the toolbar.

Comment: The array you seem to want doesn't make any sense.  You are trying to do: `['type' => '', 0 => [], 'type' => '', 1 => []]`.  You can't have multiple `type` keys.  Can you try to explain what *exactly* it is you want?

Comment: stackoverflow wouldnt let me use {} because I havent written enough "text" in comparison to amount of code. More text != better explained problem (its called waffling). I need to add type to every single level of multidimensional array and convert all numeric indexes to "own".$variable so I can do this: http://redbeanphp.com/cooker

Comment: I still don't understand.  Every level *already* has a `type` value.  Why do you want to add another?  Do you want a structure like this: `[['type' => '', 'data' => []], ['type' => '', 'data' => []]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array_insert2's second param is the position. In the first code you are actually giving it an integer making it a valid position ( $p, combined with the array_splice function ). 
In the second piece of code, the position supplied to array_insert2 is the key ( $k ) from the foreach loop on $results[$p]. The key given cannot be used correctly with the array_splice function. Maybe instead of supplying $k, give the array_search result of $k in $results[$p].

short-answer:
The position supplied in the second piece of code is not an integer, making it not usable for the array_splice function.